# Reply to message I sent puts my address in TO instead of TO from the message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail-imap, reply

I've been using Gmail for quite some time and now I'd like one its feature in Outlook 2013

- User A sends an email to user B
- User A then sends an update to this email to user B by pressing reply button.

Gmail puts original TO address in TO field of "update" message. Outlook puts sender address instead of TO. This makes "update" message being sent to User A instead of user B as User A sent the first message and is its sender.

```
If (sender == outlookAccountAddress) then
    put TO address from message user replies to instead of sender.
```

Is it possible to achieve this configuration in outlook 2013 or not? If yes then how?

Account defined in outlook is imap-gmail account. Not exchange account.

Please help since this is a dealbraker for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click the "Reply All" button instead of "Reply".